# Event/Observer for customer password change?

Tags: magento-1.7, event-observer, customer, address

I'm looking for a way to hook into the event of customers changing their passwords. So if someone changes the password in the customer frontend, I'd like to send an e-mail somewhere.

I did consult the list over at http://www.nicksays.co.uk/magento-events-cheat-sheet-1-7/ but nothing looks like an event for changing passwords.

Comment: Any idea what observer/event to use when a customer resets his password using `/customer/account/resetpassword/?id=ab&token=xyz`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Thanks to Fabian Blechschmidt, I came up with the following that works for me (using the event `customer_save_before`):

```
public function detectPwdChange(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {
    $event              = $observer->getEvent();
    $customer           = $event->getCustomer();
    $postData           = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getPost();

    if($customer instanceof Mage_Customer_Model_Customer && !$customer->isObjectNew()) {

        if( $postData['change_password'] == 1 && $postData['current_password'] != $postData['password'] ) {
            // Do something
        }
    }

    return $this;
}
```

Comment: I don't like the request on the post, but if it works, great :-)

Comment: It does work, yep. :-) I tried several methods und helper functions to get the password but all I was able to retreive was the password hash but I needed it plain readable and that's what the POST object offered. Thanks again!

Comment: Don't do weird things with the password, like saving it in plaintext or bad crypto ;-)

Comment: I won't, promised! Just sending it to PRISM. ;-)

Comment: this doesnt work as is for reset password as there is only `password` and `confirmation`in post data. tested with v1.9

Answer (score 5):

Have a look into the code.

You can use the `customer_save_after` event and just check for

```
/app/code/core/Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php:724
$customer->setChangePassword(1);
```

Maybe this value is reseted, then you have to use `save_before`, but I recommend to send the mail after the saving. So if this value is not readable in the after event, copy it to another attribute to have it by hand in the after event.

Comment: Thanks so far. As far as I can see the event is also triggered when a customer successfully registered. Is there a way/method I can check if the customer was registered already and the password actually changed?

Comment: in the _before event you can check whether an ID already exists on the object

Answer (score 4):

I wanted to do something similar, but I ended up with his code instead:

I hooked onto `controller_action_postdispatch_customer_account_resetpasswordpost`

```
function resetpasswordpost(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {
    $customer_id = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('id');
    $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($customer_id);
}
```

A bit more cleaner and "safer" than faffing about with the Password itself, I think!

Comment: `Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('id')` is null in this event. also in predispatch. `password` and `confirmation` is available in `Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParams()` tho. (Tested with v1.9)