# Generate confirmation Email after change password from frontend customer dashboard

Tags: magento-1.9, customer-account

How i can generate an email after customer change his password from frontend dashboard?

Basically i want to send confirmation email to customer after he change the password.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at this similar question where observer code and magento events will help you code a method to send an email after a password reset in the frontend.

[Event/Observer for customer password change?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/7035/event-observer-for-customer-password-change)